# Ruby on Rails: meta_tags gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-tags

I use the `meta_tags` gems to handle all the SEO meta tags.

However, when I use in my `application.html.haml` view, it's showing on the page itself so that the user sees it as well.

```
= set_meta_tags title: "app title, keywords...."
```

Any idea why that happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a behaviour of HAML rather than the meta_tags gem.

```
-# In a HAML file, ...
= '= will evaluate the ruby code and put the result on the page'
- '- will evaluate the ruby code but not put the result on the page'
```

Reference: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_evaluation